# Проблемы с position fixed у body

Tags: css

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('html,body').addClass('fixed');
});
$('close').click(function() {
  $('html,body').removeClass('fixed');
});
```

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

button {
  margin-top: 1000px;
}

html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

При открытии формы body присваивается position: fixed .Что бы устранить баг с ios при неправильном расположении курсора. При клике body автоматически листается в самый верх такое же происходит если убрать fixed. Как убрать автоматическую прокрутку вверх?

Comment: `html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

До нажатия на кнопку высота body равна высоте, необходимой чтобы вместить кнопку (100% не работает, высота в процентах работает только, если задана высота родителя или позиция absolute или fixed). Прокручивая вниз, вы прокручиваете html с автоматической высотой. Теперь вы прокрутили html до кнопки и по клику сделали html и body fixed. Без указания height для html, в котором у вас был скрол, он стал нулевой высоты и теперь вы прокручиваете body, который стал  100%, потому что он теперь fixed.

В начале вы прокручивали один элемент, затем второй.
Установите html `height: 100%`, и вы всегда будете прокручивать body.